# How can I make linear actuators go in both directions using an Arduino or other microcontroller?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, actuator, universal-motor

I'm stuck here,
[image]

I want to make the linear actuators go up and down,  both of the actuators move the same direction at the same time.

The Arduino receives a signal as input and then the ouptut of the Arduino activates the linear actuators through the MOSFET.

For the moment, I think my circuit works but only in one direction.

Could you help me with some ideas of how to make the motors go in both directions?

I thought of adding a second ouput from the Arduino, one for up and another for down, but I need to go deeper to know what is next.

Comment: Look up what an H-bridge is.

Comment: You have tagged the question [universal-motor]. A 12-volt universal motor would be very unusual and likely non-existent. Universal motors are reversal only by reversing field connection with respect to the armature. It seems more likely that the motor is a [brushed-dc-motor].

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a double-pole, double-throw (DPDT) relay, with PWM controlling the N-MOSFET gate as a speed control. Use another N-MOSFET if needed to energize the relay, can also find 5V relays with low-current coils that Arduino can control directly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEDMm6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Using a relay as a H-bridge, that's gonna click a lot and sound fun.

Comment: Linear actuator, thinking like a big screw kind of thing, doesn't change direction that much, relay seems like a good fit for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how.

[image]

K1 & K2 are relays energised by two microcontroller outputs.

With only K1 energised, the linear actuators go one way and with only K2, the other.

S1 / S3 and S2 / S4 are NC contacts of the forward and reverse limit switches, respectively. They prevent the actuators from travelling beyond their end limits.

The diodes bypass open NC contacts to enable actuator reversal.

Comment: What are the components in series with the motors? And how is this answer better than the others already submitted?

Comment: @PStechPaul - Hi Paul, I thank you for your response. My answer has been duly edited.

Answer (score 0):

When working with AC motors we just switch 2 phases to make the motor drive the opposite way, this can't really be done when working with DC, so we gotta be smart - and smart boy things always includes transistors ;)

Use whats called an H-bridge to switch directions.
I included a link that explains the H-bridge pretty well, make sure you understand the transistors you will be using for this i.e. bias levels, saturation etc etc.

https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/h-bridge/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not confident in designing an [H-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-bridge) with transistors, you could always use logic level relays such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0057OC6D8).

[image: relay module]

That would interface directly with the Arduino and is straightforward and effective. However, the design challenge of an H-bridge would be a great way to learn more, so don't shy away from that!

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6HFVuAhnpEPpjwlFJHw3qaPMqUMgvb2/view?usp=drivesdk) is the schematic of what I am describing:

[image: schematic]